# iPython not finding 1st party module

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

My company has a module (call it `company`) that they have installed and is accessible through their version of python (3.4).  But I am a fan of iPython and installed my own version of iPython (with linuxbrew).  This runs python3.5.  It might be impossible, but how can I ensure iPython will find the `company` module? The environment I launched these two programs in is the same.  But when I'm in them, the `sys.path` is different (pointing to mostly my stuff in iPython, and completely not pointing to my stiff in regular python3).  Nothing in the environment is different at launch time though.

Comment: add the path to the module to your path?  in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: ...or, if adding path is not a possibility, make sure the `company` is in your current working directory (`import os ; os.getcwd()`).

Comment: The path to the module can change at random.  yes, this is actually atrocious, I know, but I can't change it.

Comment: then make sure all possible paths are added to the path in your `.bashrc`.  how often does the path "change at random"?  if it's not very often, you could just wait for it to change, at which point your imports would start to fail, and then update the path in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: it's fairly often.  it relates to our build system.  it can be daily.

Comment: that should be a problem for everyone.  the only way it's not a problem is if everyone else's path variables are getting updated too.  and, in that case, i don't see why you can't have your path variables get updated automatically as well.  i guess i'm not seeing the root of the problem here.  what you should be doing is talking to your sys admin -- this problem seems very specific to your company, not a general computing problem.

Comment: it's also not clear to me why your wanting to use iPython necessitates that you use Python 3.5, instead of what the rest of your company uses (3.4).

Comment: and an obvious thing (which i'm just assuming is impossible for you) would be to install `company` locally (under your home directory), so you can control the location you're loading it from.  this is what @armatita was suggesting, i think.

Comment: @dbliss Yes it was. I believe this to be an X Y problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So the question is: If the path keeps changing, how do you know where it is now? (funny answer would be: a colleague told me. Which would also be a problem since my programming skills don't go as far as querying sentient species...., for now at least.)

Comment: @dbliss Ups sorry (read home as root). I actually did mean the cwd folder of his IPython session (that I assume will work just like any other executable). It should look first for the modules at it's root.